# how to know the appropriate time to know the SWAP gate operation in dipole interaction

Tags: quantum-gate, density-matrix

Consider dipole-dipole interaction between two qubits,$H_{int} = g \boldsymbol\sigma_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol\sigma_{2}=g(X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2+Z_1Z_2)$. How can I show that by turning on this interaction for an appropriate time, $U = \exp(−iH_{int}t_s)$, obtains a SWAP gate. And how we can find the value of $t_s$ in terms of $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suppose that you meant: $H_{\rm int}=g(X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2+Z_1Z_2)$ (it is unclear as you did not define your notation).
If you want to calculate:
$$U(t)=\exp[-i g t (X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2+Z_1Z_2)],$$
in that case note that $[X_1X_2,Y_1Y_2]=[Y_1Y_2,Z_1Z_2]=[X_1X_2,Z_1Z_2]=0$, so we can separate the exponential as
$$U(t)=\exp[-i g t X_1X_2]\exp[-i g t Y_1Y_2]\exp[-i g t Z_1Z_2]=R_{xx}(2tg)R_{yy}(2tg)R_{zz}(2tg)$$
where $R_{ii}$ are the Ising rotation gates. From Wikipedia [Quantum logic gates iSWAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Swap_gate) you know that
$$i\mathrm{SWAP}=R_{xx}(-\pi/2)R_{yy}(-\pi/2),$$
which is almost what you need.

With all this, you should be able to show that when $$t_s=\frac{\pi}{4g},$$
you get $U(t_s)=\mathrm{SWAP}$, up to a global phase.